# laravel and digitalocean get hangs with cached issue

Tags: php, laravel, caching, nginx

I built a Laravel app and uploaded it to digital ocean. All of that is OK, except some issues I track but can't solve.

**The problem is:**

I created a settings model with a table having key, value, and other fields.
I created this model for custom settings for my application.
Also, I created a controller to update the values and save it to cache (Note: the cache driver is array because I'm using zizaco/entrust plugin).

```
public function update(Request $request, Factory $cache)
    {
        if (!Auth::user()->hasRole(['admin','owner'])){
            return redirect(config('app.admin_prefix') . '/index');
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($request->title); $i++){
            $input['value'] = $request->value[$i];
            Settings::whereId($request->id[$i])->first()->update($input);
        }

        // When the settings have been updated, clear the cache for the key 'settings' // Back to AppServiceProvider.php
        if (Cache::has('settings')) {
            $cache->forget('settings');
        }
        $this->generateSettings();

        return redirect('/admin/settings')->with([
            'message'    => __('Admin/admin.updated_successfully'),
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ]);
    }

public function generateSettings() {
        if (Cache::has('settings')) {
            $setting = Cache::get('settings');
        } else {
            $setting = Settings::pluck('value', 'key')->all();
            if ($setting)
            {
                Cache::forever('settings', $setting);
            }
        }
        config()->set('settings', $setting);
    }
```

And I write code in appServiceProvider.php to load cached and assign it to the config:

```
public function boot()
    {
        .
        .
        .

        if (Cache::has('settings')) {
            $setting = Cache::get('settings');
        } else {
            $setting = Settings::pluck('value', 'key')->toArray();
            if ($setting) {
                Cache::forever('settings', $setting);
            }
        }
        config()->set('settings', $setting);
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Now my error appears sometimes when I'm testing or refreshing the page. I see this message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select `value`, `key` from `settings`)
```

Should I wait for some time until the page works, or should I restart Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've run out of characters in the comment, I will post this as an answer.

To me, the problematic part seems to be at this lines

```
if (Cache::has('settings')) {
    $cache->forget('settings');
}
```

If you could rewrite the code, so the cache is not deleted but overridden the problem should disappear. So my suggestion is to do it this way:

```
public function update(Request $request, Factory $cache)
    {
    if (!Auth::user()->hasRole(['admin','owner'])){
        return redirect(config('app.admin_prefix') . '/index');
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($request->title); $i++){
        $input['value'] = $request->value[$i];
        Settings::whereId($request->id[$i])->first()->update($input);
    }

    $this->generateSettings();

    return redirect('/admin/settings')->with([
        'message'    => __('Admin/admin.updated_successfully'),
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    ]);
}

public function generateSettings() 
{
        $setting = Settings::pluck('value', 'key')->all();
        if ($setting){
            Cache::forever('settings', $setting);
        }
        config()->set('settings', $setting);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @veNuker

i'll try your solution, but what about appserviceprovider? i think the error from there....

Comment: ```
[2017-11-29 09:17:07] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select `value`, `key` from `settings`) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select `value`, `key` from `settings`) at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67)
[stacktrace]

Comment: And this error is still random or does it happen all the time?

Comment: Actually, i installed redis and error is solved today :) 

Appreciate your helps :)